# Mysql REGEXP to search the name of product

Tags: php, mysql, regex, laravel

I have field pruduct_name in the table product
the record of product_name are

- Hydrant Box Indoor Type A1 65x52x15cm w/o Glass&Lock
- Hydrant Box Indoor Type A2 100x80x18cm w/o Glass&Lock
- Hydrant Box Indoor Type B 125x75x18cm w/o Glass&Lock
- Hydrant Box Outdoor Type C 95x66x20cm w/o Glass&Lock
- Hydrant Box Indoor Type C 95x66x20cm w/o Glass&Lock

what i want to do is when i search "Hydrant box type c"
then only Hydrant box with "type c" are appears.

I have try these :

`$prd_name= str_replace(' ','.+',$query);`

`$get_data = DB::table('product')->whereRaw('product_name regexp "'.$prd_name.'"')->select("product_name as name")->get();`

But the result also showing the another type

Comment: You could simply match like `product_name like '%Hydrant box%type c%'` but this is not a generic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning:** This answer does not covers `Mysql REGEXP`.

**This is only a workaround using Mysql LIKE and PHP**:

Use [php explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split your search parameter by word, then use `where` conditions with each word.

Try the code given below:

```
//get user input
$searchParam    = $request->get('search_field_name');
//split user input to words array
$searchParamArr = explode(" ", $searchParam);

$query = Product::query;
//loop through each word
foreach ($searchParamArr as $value) {
    //apply where condition with each word
    $query = $query->where("product_name", "LIKE", $value);
}

$get_data = $query->get();
```

This will work as per your sample data. But there would be an issue in the following scenario:

your data:

- Hydrant Box Indoor Type A1
- Hydrant A1
  Indoor Type Box

Even though the above data differs but both have same words in it.
If you search for `Hydrant Box A1` the code will return both lines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it help me so much

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern and key world LIKE:

```
$users = DB::table('product')
                ->where('name', 'like', '%Hydrant box%type c%')
                ->get();
```

This code will search products that have "T" in name. Try to adopt it.

Here tou have doc and more examples: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

Good luck!

Comment: i've tried it. but it just search anything in the beginning and end of parameter. 
if i type "Hydrant box type c" it wouldn't show anything because no such item like this.